# Partition array to hash in ruby

Tags: ruby

Problem: convert this array of hashes:

```
cars = [
  { :model=>"Ferrari 458", :speed=>320 },
  { :model=>"Maserati MC12", :speed=>330 },
  { :model=>"Ferrari Enzo", :speed=>350 },
  { :model=>"Lamborghini Huracan", :speed=>325 }
]
```

to this data structure:

```
{
  above_320: [
    { :model=>"Maserati MC12", :speed=>330 },
    { :model=>"Lamborghini Huracan", :speed=>325 },
    { :model=>"Ferrari Enzo", :speed=>350 }
  ],
  the_rest: [
    { :model=>"Ferrari 458", :speed=>320 }
  ]
}
```

My solution:

```
cars.partition {|car| car[:speed] > 320}
.map.with_index {|cars,i| [ i == 0 ? :above_320 : :the_rest, cars ]}
.to_h
```

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go with the `chunk` method:

```
cars.chunk { |c| c[:speed]>320 ? :above_320 : :the_rest }.to_h
```

Though it's important to underline that `chunk` doesn't work if the array is not ordered (by speed in this case). In that case we need to prepend it with `sort_by`:

```
cars.sort_by {|car| car[:speed]}.chunk { |c| c[:speed]>320 ? :above_320 : :the_rest }.to_h
```

(Moreover, if we want to order the hash keys, like in the example, we need to call `sort` after `chunk`):

```
cars.sort_by {|car| car[:speed]}.chunk { |c| c[:speed]>320 ? :above_320 : :the_rest }.sort.to_h
```

Comment: Thanks! It's a thing that popped up from a pet project actually :-)

Answer (score 2):

I think that `.map.with_index {|cars,i| [ i == 0 ? :above_320 : :the_rest, cars ]}` is a bit more verbose and awkward than it needs to be.

```
Hash[
  [:above_320, :the_rest].zip(cars.partition { |car| car[:speed] > 320 })
]
```

Alternatively,

```
[:above_320, :the_rest]
  .zip(cars.partition { |car| car[:speed] > 320 })
  .to_h
```